# Ajax Multi Response Problem

Tags: ajax

When I was trying to get multi-response from php shortcode function, I had the strange result with its Json output.
In my php,

```
$result['success']=false;
$result['string']='You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!';
echo json_encode($result);
```

In js file

```
$.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, {         //POST request
      ...............
    }, function(data) {                //callback
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);  
});
```

But in my result, I got the

`{"success":"true","string":"You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!"}0`

I don't know why I got the number 0 at the behind of result.

Comment: Normally, shortcodes don't echo they return. I imagine we would need to see more code here.

Comment: Give full code details

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#die):

> When the handler has finished all of its tasks, it needs to die. If
>   you are using the [WP_Ajax_Response](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_ajax_response/) or wp_send_json* functions, this is
>   automatically handled for you. If not, simply use the WordPress
>   [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) function.
>
> ```
> wp_die();
> // That's all folks!
> ```

So you either need to use:

```
$result['success'] = false;
$result['string']  = 'You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!';
echo json_encode( $result );
wp_die();
```

Or

```
$result['success'] = false;
$result['string']  = 'You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!';
wp_send_json( $result );
```

You can also send a JSON with the `success` property set to `false` for you like this:

```
$result = 'You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!';
wp_send_json_error( $result, 400 );
```

That will result in something like:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": "You have not uploaded project file, please upload first!"
}
```